# Ruby on Rails (`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I keep getting this error when trying to compile a 15 year old Ruby site.

```
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:109:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `block in build'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `inject'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in `block in app'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:45:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Sites/Greyville/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any idea how I may fix? It's past Ruby 3, so not using Ruby 2. If I use Ruby 3 it comes up with this error. If I use Ruby 2, it's a lot more errors.

Comment: If the site is 15 years old you probably need to be looking at Ruby 1.x... is there a .ruby-version file or any clue as to which version it was written in?

Comment: @PaulM please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617925/rails-server-exiting-after-starting).

Comment: @Mark its not 15 years old. Rails 0.8 was released in 2009 and I highly doubt it predates that. The stack trace also hints that this is using Rails 5.1.7 which was released in 2019 (railties is an internal gem and is versioned in lockstep with Rails).

Comment: 5.1.7 is not compatible with Ruby 3 or any Ruby version thats currently supported. You need to find a compatible Ruby version and keep updating the app until you can run it on modern ruby versions.

Comment: *"Any idea how I may fix?"* -- Start by trying to figure out what version of ruby (and any other known dependencies??) the application was last successfully running with. There's no way it was using rails 5.1.7 (released March 2019) with ruby 3.1 (released Dec 2021, and not compatible with rails 5). Look at the `Gemfile.lock`, or for a `.ruby-version`. If you've randomly tried upgrading anything else then stop, revert all your changes, and go back to the latest known working version of the source code.

Comment: I'd suggest looking back through the git commit history. You can use the dates when key gems were first installed and search for what gems were current on those dates. Same goes for dating which version of Rails and friends.

Comment: @max's comment helped me. My app was very small so I tried simply updating the rails gem version in `Gemfile` (from 5xx to 6xx) and it worked right away for me.